# Why don't calls to emergency numbers show in the Phone app's call log?

Tags: calls, 8.1-oreo, nexus-6p, emergency-calls

I recently had to make an emergency call.

I later noticed in my device's call logs in the Phone app that the emergency number I called doesn't show up in the call log. (In other words, no entry shows of the call; no trace in the call log that I called an emergency number.)

Why is this? Is this intentional and by design, or is it a bug?

(Using stock Android 8.1 with latest updates on Nexus 6P.)

Answer (score 1):

Logically they should for traceability of crank / genuine distress emergency calls. As a matter of fact   [Call  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html#EXTRA_LAST_EMERGENCY_CALLBACK_TIME_MILLIS) specifies *extra time accuracy* for emergency calls:

> Extra key used to indicate the time (in **milliseconds** since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC) when the last outgoing emergency call was made. **This is used to identify potential emergency callbacks**

(Emphasis supplied)

Try changing the call app and if it still persists report to OEM / ROM developers

Related [What's the purpose of "Emergency Call" button on SIM unlock screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43546)

Comment: I am not a developer, sharing my understanding as user. On my device mia1, it showed up in logs in past and now too - just checked

Comment: In my Nexus 6 and OnePlus 6, dialing 112 always shows up in the call logs.